# TinyMCE: using maxchars plugin in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I've got a Rails app that is using TinyMCE, via the TinyMCE-Rails gem.  I'm trying to use the maxchars plugin to get word count going.  I've added the plugin to config/tinymce.yml

```
plugins:
  - fullscreen
  - maxchars
```

And I've added the max_chars and max_chars_indicators to my view.

```
<%= simple_form_for @project |f| %>
  <%= f.input :overview, input_html: { :class => "tinymce", :rows => 70, :cols => 140 } %>
  <%= tinymce max_chars: 6000, max_chars_indicator: "characterCounter" %>
  <div id="characterCounter">

   </div>

   <div class="form-actions add-top">
     <hr>
     <p>
       <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'inline-block large_button add-bottom' %>
     </p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But now the editor doesn't even appear.  Is there something I'm missing when it comes to adding this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex solution for this problem: had to actually read the documentation!  (Outrageous, right?!)

I had neglected to actually download the plugin files.  I created a directory, `app/assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins/` and popped in the folder containing the necessary JS files.  Once I started my server, everything worked great.